# Wpf datagrid more than one filter in one datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have 3 columns in my datagrid for example name ,regno,age  and I need add two filters  like by name and age in wpf how can i do?I am using datagrid.I am using observable collection.

Comment: What kind of collection are you using?

Comment: observable collection

Comment: http://nosalan.blogspot.in/2013/10/wpf-datagrid-with-filtering-mvvm.html gone through this link..